# RedHat 7 Basic Web Server subscription

Tags: redhat, rhel7

I have a test server using RedHat 7.2 "Basic web Server" option, no addon.

After installation things seems to work, except for the subscription, and without this I cannot do yum search somepackage or yum install somepackage.

I did

```
subscription-manager register --username MYEMAIL --password MYPASSWORD --auto-attach
```

That did not fix the issue.

```
[root@myserver~]# subscription-manager attach --auto


Installed Product Current Status:
Product Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
Status:       Not Subscribed

Unable to find available subscriptions for all your installed products.
```

I can tell from "https://access.redhat.com/management/consumers" that I have other Redhat systems which successfully subscribed to

"Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Suite"  "Self-Support"

Any idea why?